# predict.tree function throws "eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found" when wrapping it into a function

Tags: r, tree, decision-tree, rpart

I am trying to write a function to wrap the fitting and prediction of a regression tree with the function `tree::tree`,

```r
test = function(n = 100, p = 10){
    x = matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n)
    y = rnorm(n)
    treefit = tree(y ~ x)
    predict(treefit)
}
```

but the prediction step throws an error that

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found

Later, I tried to find the reason by printing some internal steps of `predict.tree` (the code can be found in the source file `treefix.R` of package `tree`), the related sentences are

```
    if(missing(newdata) || is.null(newdata)) {
        where <- object$where
        newdata <- model.frame(object)
        if(!is.null(object$call$weights))
            nwts <- model.extract(model.frame(object), "weights")
    } else {
```

and I found that the error is exactly caused by `model.frame(object)`.

If I remove the wrapping of the function, i.e.,

```r
n = 100; p = 10
x = matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n)
y = rnorm(n)
treefit = tree(y ~ x)
predict(treefit)
```

it works well.

And if I replace `tree::tree` with `rpart::rpart`, the wrapping function would work well.

I have made sure that the environments are always clean via `rm(list=ls())` before running the above tests.

My session info is that

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rpart_4.1-15 tree_1.0-40 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3    packrat_0.5.0
```

I am quite curious why this bug occurs, and why two different behaviors with/without wrapping function, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because `predict.tree()`, as well as all the other predict methods, require the argument `newdata`. The code below solves your problem assuming you want to predict using the model defined by `treefit` over the same dataset defined in `df`.

```r
library(tree)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tree':
#>   method     from
#>   print.tree cli

test = function(n = 100, p = 10){
  x = matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n)
  y = rnorm(n)
  df = data.frame( y = y, x = x )
  treefit = tree(y ~ x, data = df)
  predict(treefit, newdata = df)
}

test()
#>           1           2           3           4           5           6 
#>  0.51330588 -0.32181288 -0.32181288 -1.09139248  1.23169698 -1.09139248 
#>           7           8           9          10          11          12 
#> -1.31747689  0.40441313 -1.27146030 -0.11833993  0.05239198  0.40441313 
#>          13          14          15          16          17          18 
#>  1.23169698  1.53901928  0.85394688  0.05239198 -0.17877693 -1.09139248 
#>          19          20          21          22          23          24 
#> -1.31747689  1.43556344 -0.32181288  0.21124359  1.23169698  0.85394688 
#>          25          26          27          28          29          30 
#>  0.51330588 -1.31747689  0.40441313  0.51330588  0.85394688  0.21124359 
#>          31          32          33          34          35          36 
#>  1.43556344 -1.31747689 -0.03165166 -1.27146030  0.40441313  0.21124359 
#>          37          38          39          40          41          42 
#> -1.27146030 -1.31747689  0.51330588 -0.71497537 -0.71497537  1.53901928 
#>          43          44          45          46          47          48 
#> -0.03165166 -0.11833993  0.05239198  1.53901928 -1.09139248 -0.11833993 
#>          49          50          51          52          53          54 
#>  0.05239198  0.21124359 -0.11833993  1.53901928  1.53901928  0.85394688 
#>          55          56          57          58          59          60 
#> -0.03165166 -0.17877693 -0.03165166  1.53901928  0.40441313  0.21124359 
#>          61          62          63          64          65          66 
#> -0.03165166 -0.11833993 -0.17877693  1.53901928  1.43556344 -0.17877693 
#>          67          68          69          70          71          72 
#> -0.71497537  0.40441313 -0.71497537  1.43556344 -1.27146030  1.23169698 
#>          73          74          75          76          77          78 
#> -0.17877693 -0.32181288  0.21124359 -1.09139248 -1.31747689 -0.03165166 
#>          79          80          81          82          83          84 
#>  0.85394688  0.85394688 -1.09139248 -0.32181288 -0.03165166  1.53901928 
#>          85          86          87          88          89          90 
#>  1.43556344  0.51330588  0.05239198  0.51330588 -0.03165166 -0.11833993 
#>          91          92          93          94          95          96 
#> -0.03165166 -0.71497537 -1.31747689 -0.11833993  0.85394688  1.53901928 
#>          97          98          99         100 
#>  0.40441313  1.23169698  1.23169698 -1.27146030
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. But based on my past experience, the default `predict` without arguments would directly return the fitted value, and as shown by `predict.rpart`, mentioned in my question. Also, the source code of `predict.tree` indeed seems to support an empty `newdata` argument, but it fails to extract the original data frame, where the related code has been pasted in the question.

Comment: The default value passed to `newdata` in `predict.tree()` is a `list()`. I guess that's why you are having this issue. Your call to decide whether the proposed solution works or not.

Comment: I think the default `list()` might not be the reason, since the source code later use `missing(newdata)` to check if the `newdata` is provided, which is still TRUE regardless there is a default value or not. And the error message comes from `newdata <- model.frame(object)` as mentioned in my question.